# Расползается текст в андроид браузере

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, кроссбраузерность

Везде нормально отображается, а в стандартном андроид браузере расползается текст. Пробовал задать letter-spacing: 0px!important; не сработало...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сайт sherlok lviv ua

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом добавляем в CSS

```
* {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Пробуем сконвертировать PX в EM.
Поверяем, есть ли SVG файл подключенного шрифта.

Это первое, что я бы сделал для устранения этой проблемы.

Comment: не помогло, но все ровно спасибо!

Comment: А если поставить любой стандартный шрифт?

Comment: тоже пробовал....

Comment: А на других устройствах? Я вот не вижу проблем в стандартном браузере.